# login screen with google+ and using shared preferences to track logged-in user in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I searched many sites but i didn't find the exact code where login can happen through google+ only and shared preferences is used to track the logged-in user. I tried watching some videos but they make a custom login page instead of using google+ to login your app.
Shall i integrate google+ first and then perform the shared preferences part or vice-versa?
I am totally new to this so, can anybody suggest me the steps in which i have to proceed one by one and also if any useful link is available??

Comment: did you try this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#configure_google_sign-in_and_the_googleapiclient_object ?

Comment: As i am totally new to this so its hard to understand the link that you have sent. Moreover i have to use only single activity for the note taking app so, i think have to use fragment for integrating this sign-in feature. Please help me in a step by step elaborated way to make this type of login screen

Comment: Here is what you need: https://github.com/CommonUtils/Social-Signin-Android . An easy implementation of all third party logins.

Comment: @KevalPatel : as i have to make a note taking app and i have to use only a single activity for my app so shall i integrate google+ login in a frame or an activity?

Comment: @Guneet: Yes can integrate either in fragment or activity. That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Any approach is fine depends on which approach you are comfortable with..

i would prefer to implement G+ first then go on with tracking user session using shared preference..

Comment: can you suggest some site having the exact code for this and moreover as i have to make the note taking app further so i have to do everything in a single activity. So, i'll be very grateful if you could guide me in step by step approach.